# ResultSet vs RowSet: Which one to choose and when?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc, rowset

So I'm aware of some relative differences i.e., the `ResultSet` has an 'open connection' to the database whereas a `RowSet` works in a 'disconnected' fashion.

But that's pretty much what I understand (may be incorrect):

My question is then this - under what circumstances is one preferable over the other? What are each of their strengths/weaknesses?

- From what I feel a `RowSet`, working in
  disconnected mode especially for
  "read-only" queries, would have
  better performance in a highly
  concurrent system. Is that correct?
  If that's the case is it safe to say
  `RowSet` is always preferable to
  `ResultSet` for readonly queries?
- If I'm correct iterating over the
  `RowSet` doesn't throw SQL Exceptions,
  but is that a benefit? The other
  being that `RowSet` is serializable.
  But my concern is primarily from a
  performance perspective what would be
  the choice?
- But does it even matter for
  read-write queries?? Can you sync the
  ResultSet back to the DB? (I'm not
  sure if that's possible (It may be
  and I just can't recollect or google
  it well enough :) It's been a while
  with raw JDBC...

Any ideas? There are some missing gaps in my knowledge as is evident :)

The reason I ask is I'd like to choose between implementing Spring-JDBC's `ResultSetExtractor` Interface versus return an `SqlRowSet` when processing some data. This question just got me curious to how to decide what to choose when, other than tossing a coin :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### RowSet

[`RowSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/RowSet.html) is almost always the right choice, it is more full featured and has all the benefits you listed as well as having specialized implementations for special purposes, like the disconnected `CachedRowSet` which is what I always use when the data will fit into memory, so I can release the connection back to the pool as quickly as possible to be reused.

#### `ResultSet` should never be part of a public contract.

A connected `ResultSet/Rowset` should never escape the method or at worst the object that created them. At least with a `RowSet` you can disconnect it and the client doesn't have to care about the implementation. *Unless you are writing `JDBC` specific library code that interacts or relies on `ResultSet` specific features or contracts.

If you are just transferring the results of a query, `JDBC` specific classes should be part of your public contract.

#### Ideally you want to materialize `RowSet/ResultSet` contents to typesafe Domain Objects to pass around.

In most cases you want to materialize a `List/Set` of domain objects to manipulate and work with instead of coupling your code directly to the `JDBC` api.

Many modern takes on a `ResultSetMapper<T>` class exist to handle generating typesafe domain instances using a `Visitor` pattern because this is the idiomatic way of doing things.

Comment: When some legacy third party API requires it as an input to a method.

Answer (score 26):

I disagree with JR's answer.  The RowSet is often a good choice, but as always, the best answer depends on your situation and your needs.  Using a RowSet for everything won't yield dysfunctional code, but it can offer slower performance than a ResultSet (the common JdbcRowSet implementation is a wrapper for a ResultSet).

If you need to use your result object in modular code that requires a JavaBean, then RowSets meet the minimum requirements for Java Beans.

If you are developing code for a multithreaded/server app, then you must accept the concession that all Java Beans are mutable and therefore not thread-safe.  As a result, neither Resultset nor RowSets are thread safe.

If you are writing code that consumes database queries and translates them into Java data model objects for use in the rest of your application, then it is likely that RowSets are less performant than Resultsets.

In a lot of code that I've been writing, when I receive a JDBC database query, I've been simply using the Resultset to process the retrievd rows immediately into a List of data model objects.  The Resultset doesn't even survive the method call that performs the translation.  In my opinion, this is good ... because Resultsets (and therefore RowSets) consume a lot of resources, and you want them to be available for gc as soon as you can.

In this mode, I don't even need any of the newer features of Resultset, let alone RowSet.  I simply iterate forward once through the set and generate a List of result rows.

There are situations in which RowSets are highly desirable.  Since RowSets are serializable and ostensibly "lightweight", the disconnected CachedRowSet (for example) represents a reasonably efficient mechanism for transmitting database query results between locations, particularly if you want the data to be updateable in situ.  Of course, you could also serialize and transmit a List of objects.

Comment: connected ResultSets should never escape the method they are created in or in the worse case the object that owns them, thus they should never be part of a public api.

Comment: All JavaBeans are **not** mutable if you do not provide `getters` and make all instance references `private final` and the referenced objects are immutable as well concurrency is easy then.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson *"All JavaBeans are not mutable...."* ... I must disagree.  Sure, you could make a JavaBean object *effectively final* by initializing it and then assuring that its state can never change ... but ... how would you do this?  You could do it by implementing a thread-safe state machine as part of the JavaBean class or by making the JavaBean emulate an immutable class (as you suggest) by making fields `final`.  In the former case, it can still be possible to observe the class instance in an inconsistent state ... and in the latter case you don't really have a JavaBean.

Comment: standard conforming *"JavaBeans"* have not be a real concern of any since about 2005, much less 2013 when this answer was written and especially not in 2018 and beyond. They were are bad idea when they were created and it was very quickly realized as such. It is very clear that immutable data structures have way more benefits than negatives, even 3 years ago and are the preferred design choice. Now when people say *JavaBean* they really are mean *POJO*, no-arg constructor, getter/setter *JavaBean* conformance has been a dead consideration for almost 15 years.